# Django queryset: aggregate after slicing the queryset doesn't work

Tags: python, django, aggregate, slice, django-queryset

```
Car.objects.all() # 5 cars in db, every car costs 1000 $

Car.objects.all().aggregate(Sum("price")) # result: 5000

# aggregate only on a subset

Car.objects.all()[3:].aggregate(Sum("price")) # result: 5000!, not 3000

# with filter()[3:] i got the same results!
```

Why? Slicing is not evaluated in db?

How can i achieve that with aggregate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aggregate` works by modifying the query sent to the DB, causing aggregation to happen on the DB side.  You have two choices.

1. You can use `filter` to reduce your QuerySet before using `aggregate`, instead of slicing to reduce it.
2. You have to do your aggregation in Python, e.g. `sum(car.price for car in cars)` after slicing. Once you slice, the query is sent to the database, so you can no longer aggregate through the ORM (i.e. QuerySet methods).

Comment: looks like django now supports aggregate after slicing. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 5):

It seems it is not possible to use aggregation on slicing as this open ticket suggest: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12886

One solution is to execute two distinct queries. The first one to retrieve the sub set of Cars and the second one to actually perform the aggregation:

```
qs = Car.objects.all()[:3]
sub_sum = Car.objects.filter(pk__in=qs).aggregate(Sum("price"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.7 (back in 2014) you can aggregate a slice.